# Convert the line $x(t)=(2,3)+t(1,-3)$ into point-normal form

Tags: linear-algebra

Convert the line $x(t)=(2,3)+t(1,-3)$ into point-normal form.

So, I know that the point-normal form is $n \cdot (x-p)$  and the given line equation above is in point-parallel form, which is $x(t)=P + tv$.

From looking at it, $(2,3)$ is a point, and $(1,-3)$ is a vector. Although I have the vector, I need to find the normal vector in order to complete my point-normal form $n \cdot (x-(2,3))$.

How would I find the normal vector for $n$?

Answer (score 2):

If $(a,b)$ is a given vector then $(-b,a)$ (also the opposite $(b,-a)$) is perpendicular to $(a,b).$ Indeed

$$(a,b)\cdot (-b,a)=-ab+ab=0.$$ So, in your case the vector you are looking for is $$\vec{n}=(3,1).$$ (Of course, you can take $\vec{n}=(-3,-1)$ or any other multiple of $(3,1).$)

Comment: $(3,1)$ is the answer I got as well! But the answer in my textbook is $(-3,-1) \cdot (x-(2,3))=0$

Comment: Note that $(-3,-1)=-(3,1).$ So, if $(3,1)$ is perpendicular to the line then $(-3,-1)$ is also a normal vector of the line. Note that both equations are essentially the same. They only differ by a minus sign.

Comment: I see. They are both perpendicular to the line. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.